# How to check the availability of environment variables correctly?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I did a token check, if at least one token is missing, 'True' will not be. Now I need to deduce which variable is missing, how to do it?

```
PRACTICUM_TOKEN = os.getenv('PRACTICUM_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID')


def check_tokens():
    """Checks the availability of environment variables."""
    ENV_VARS = [PRACTICUM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID]
    if not all(ENV_VARS):
        print('Required environment variables are missing:', ...)
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell which element is false when using `all`. Use an explicit loop

Comment: As a friendly word of warning, using environment variables in a program, especially when tokens (or other ‘security-related’ elements) are involved, introduces a substantial security risk, as env vars can be overwritten by a malicious (or accidental naive) user; resulting in a security breach.

Comment: @S3DEV That's definitely something to be considered for your architecture, but generally I'm okay with it if the user has a properly guarded user-space, with proper understanding of code/libraries being invoked, proper thoughts to sudo rules, etc. For services deployed on systems like K8S, I think secret environment variables are fine as long as you set up frequent secret rotations and redeployments as part of the app lifecycle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might suggest putting these values inside a class. The check tokens method can be part of the class, and you can use `__dict__` to dynamically get reference to all of the tokens you defined without having to duplicate code.

```
class Environment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.PRACTICUM_TOKEN = os.getenv('PRACTICUM_TOKEN')
        self.TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
        self.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID')

    def check_tokens(self):
        """Checks the availability of environment variables."""
        missing_vars = [var for var, value in self.__dict__.items() if not value]
        if missing_vars:
            print('Required environment variables are missing:', *missing_vars)
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(Environment().check_tokens())
```

Comment: thank you! a very interesting solution, but I need check_tokens() to be able to exist outside the class, my study pytests do not pass with this solution.

Comment: @finegorko, you can easily rewrite `check_tokens` as a function accepting an instance of `Environment`, like I did in my answer.

Comment: thank you man! i did like this https://pastecode.io/s/c3082pvr

Answer (score 6):

A minimal adaptation of your code:

```
PRACTICUM_TOKEN = os.getenv('PRACTICUM_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID')

ENV_VARS = ['PRACTICUM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID']


def check_tokens():
    """Checks the availability of environment variables."""
    undefined_vars = set(filter(lambda v: globals().get(v) is not None,
                                ENV_VARS))
    if not undefined_vars:
        return True
    print(f"Required environment variables are missing: {undefined_vars}")
    return False
```

---

But I hate writing lines like `FOO = bar('FOO')`, so here's a more complicated approach, partly inspired by *flakes* answer:

```
class Environment:
    env_vars = ['PRACTICUM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID']

    def __init__(self):
        for var in self.env_vars:
            setattr(self, var, os.getenv(var))


def check_tokens(e):
    """checks the availability of environment variables."""
    undefined_vars = set(filter(lambda v: not getattr(e, v), e.env_vars))
    if not undefined_vars:
        return True
    print(f"Required environment variables are missing: {undefined_vars}")
    return False


env = Environment()
check_tokens(env)
```

```
 $ TELEGRAM_TOKEN=1 python3 envvars.py
Required environment variables are missing: {'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID', 'PRACTICUM_TOKEN'}
```

Comment: I think this is missing a feature. The env-variables in this example aren't exposed as python variables with defined names.

Comment: @flakes: good point, I've amended the answer =)

Comment: I think you could make this even cooler with a dataclass like syntax. Example: https://pastecode.io/s/f8nst7s5

Comment: Wow, what a twisted mind you have, don't you? =) Very cool!